# Uploaded file won't open (incorrect directory) from table (PHP,MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, hyperlink

Sorry if this is something stupid but just looking for some genuine help. Struggling with this.

I have a HTML script that uploads a file called `minegem.html` which when submitted calls `minegem.php` This script uploads the data from the form into the table, uploads a file to a directory, and gives the user a table to view said data. It all works quite nicely.

```
<?php

//define variables to be used
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '';

$database = 'minetech';
$table = 'minegem';
$directory = 'uploads/minegem/';

//This gets all the other information from the form
$name=$_POST['docname'];
$version=$_POST['docver'];
$date=$_POST['docdate'];
$type=$_POST['doctype'];
$author=$_POST['docauth'];

//target directory is assigned
$target = $directory;
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 

//if everything is ok upload the file
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} 
else {
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}

//connect to sql
$con = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_user","$db_pwd");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

//connect to database
mysql_select_db("$database", $con);

//insert data from form to database
$sql="INSERT INTO $table (DocName, DocVer, DocDate, DocType, DocAuth, DocLoc)
VALUES
('$name','$version','$date','$type','$author','$target')";

//confirm data entry
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo " and new record added. How cool is that.";


//the following script displays the data for test purposes


//this script will show table data
//retrieve tables values
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

//build table and define headings
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Version</th>
<th>Upload Date</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Uploader</th>
<th>Location</th>
</tr>";


// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['DocName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['DocVer'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['DocDate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['DocType'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['DocAuth'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['DocLoc'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_free_result($result);

//close connecition to database
mysql_close($con)
?>`
```

Both of the files are located in `C:/wamp/www/` so when I run them via web browser it shows as `localhost/minegem.php`

I have a final script which will be the one I actually run to show the end user the results.

```
<?php

//define variables to be used
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '';

$database = 'minetech';
$table = 'minegem';
$type = 'Guideline';

//connect to sql
$con = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_user","$db_pwd");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

//connect to database
mysql_select_db("$database", $con);

//this script will show table data
//retrieve tables values
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table
WHERE DocType='Guideline'");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

//build table and define headings
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Document Name</th>
<th>Version</th>
</tr>";


// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$docname=$row['DocName'];
$docver=$row['DocVer'];
$doctype=$row['DocType'];
$docloc=$row['DocLoc'];

echo "<tr>";
echo '<td><a href='.urlencode($docloc).'>'.$docname.'</a></td>';
echo "<td>$docver</td>";
echo "</tr>";


}
echo "</table>";


mysql_free_result($result);

//close connecition to database
mysql_close($con)

?>
```

My first table shows the file location as `uploads/minegem/test document.pdf`
The second table that display that as a link shows in the address bar `http://localhost/uploads%2Fminegem%2Ftest+document.pdf`
And on the page is says 
`The requested URL /uploads/minegem/test+document.pdf was not found on this server.`

I assume this is a stupid file structure problem but its crucial. I will end up putting this on a server so being able to store the complete file patch and recall that as a link would be great. I'm hoping someone can help point me in the right direction with setting up correct file structures. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I have gotten it working. First I assigned a variable of $file  `$file=$_FILES['uploaded']['name'];`  Then I use that variable to store in the table instead of $target. Now when I call the table up I can rawcodeurl $docloc which is just the filename incl extension, and I manually added the folder location. I may simplify this and add a variable for that as well  `echo '<td><a href="/uploads/minegem/'.rawurlencode($docloc).'">'.$docname.'</a></td>';`  Now my files are linking and opening correctly. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rawurlencode instead. This replaces the space with a %20 and not a plus sign.

The + is used for transfer of data, the %20 for URLs that are displayed for clicking on. Although you can always user %20 for data transfer, you can only sometimes use +, if browsers incorrectly support it. So stick with rawurlencode.

Also, rawurlencode the basename part only before insertion into the database. This leaves the path not urlencoded. I don't think this but is breaking your code, but it's a lot neater.

---

Answering Q) how to rawurlencode just the basename.

A) Just store the basename in the database. You know the path ($directory) and so you can use move_uploaded_file(..., $directory . $target);  and then when outputting the file location, use a href="http://localhost/'.$directory.rawurlencode($target) . '"

---

But a couple of other "issues" that are also very important.

1. When you output the text to screen for display, make sure you use httpspecialchars() on it.

   [a href="http://localhost/'.$directory.rawurlencode($target).'"]'.$directory.httpspecialchars($target).'[/a]   // Replace square brackets with angle brackets - can't enter angle brackets here.
2. When saving to database at a minimum use "mysql_real_escape_string" to make it safe for entering into the database. But is it **STRONGLY** recommended to use PDO or mysqli (mysql functions are being depreciated, where as PDO and mysqli are both safer to use by design)

Comment: Thanks Robbie. That sounds like it will do the trick. How can I rawurlencode just the basename though?

Comment: Have added more in the answer. Includes some tips to make safe for entering data into a database and also for displaying info on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Is it crucial to have the filename as test document.pdf? You might as well work on renaming the file in PHP:

```
<?php
//your upload script here



$filename = $_POST['filename']; //change this to the variable which stores filename
$new_filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename);
rename('c:/wamp/uploads/minegem/'.$filename,   
       'c:/wamp/uploads/minegem/'.$new_filename); 

?>
```

Then try to access it again. Spaces in filenames are really trouble when you access them on the browser.

Comment: I am trying to set a site up where documents etc can be uploaded by users (its a closed site) to the server, and a table generated showing the file name which links to that file. Then users can click that link and open it. I am a complete noob to PHP etc and I feel this is just a directory problem. I don't need to be able to view the file in the browser, just access them from the links in my table.

Comment: I have added an extra row to my final table which displays this;

`echo '<td><a href="C:/wamp/www/'.urlencode($docloc).'">'.$docname.'</a></td>';`

Now when I hover over the link it shows `file:///C:/wamp/www/minegem%2F/uploads%2Ftest+document.pdf`

I would assume this to be correct but its still not loading the file. Clicking the link does nothing.

Comment: the code above should be place right after your upload script so that it renames the uploaded file into something that doesn't have spaces in the filename. Then the filenames in your table would all have underscores instead of spaces. Let me know if something isn't clear so that I could explain it further.

Comment: @Hux: that's not the way to do it. See the other answer below. It might be easier for you to follow.

Comment: I have added your code but no matter what variable I place in `['filename']` it tells me it is undefined.

Comment: @Hux: its this one: $_FILES['uploaded']['name'].